# How to forward style object to styled component?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Imagine I create a react component

and users can use it but I want to allow users to pass a typical style object to it:

```
<Text style={{color:"red",borderRadius:10}}/>
```

Now imagine this `Text` component uses *styled component* inside:

```
// Inside Text Component render method
...
return (
    <TextContainerStyled {...props.style}>
```

`TextContainerStyled`   is a styled component. How do I forward the style object which user supplies to `Text`  component to `TextContainerStyled` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, I think you need an implementation like this

```
const TextContainerStyled = styled.div``

const Text = (props)=>{
  return (
    <TextContainerStyled style={props.style}>
     {/* Other children here */}
    </TextContainerStyled/>
  )
}
```

This doesn't however forward refs, if you want to forward a the `Text` ref to the `TextContainer` too. You might need to read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: yeah so it forwards the style? I thought it forwarded only valid DOM props if underlying component was not react component

Comment: You will have to use `Text` like `<Text style={{ ...yourStylesYouWantToPass }} />`. By default, it doesn't forward anything. It will only forward the props you tell it to. If you want it to forward everything, then you will have to spread the props of `Text` into `TextContainerStyled`

Comment: I mean **TextContainerStyled**  forwarded it to the **div**. That is what I meant with forwarding. I didn't know it would forward it.Docs say it would forward only valid DOM attributes, which style is not

Comment: Instead of forwarding the style object. You can implement it in a way that you will just be able to do something like

`'const StyledText = styled(Text)``'`. You can read about how to do that here(https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components)

Comment: No I want user to pass the style object to the component